# MySQL nested select statement issues

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to get my nested SQL statement to work.

It tells me I have a syntax error near the second SELECT.

Can anyone advise?

```
SELECT date, Expense_Date, cost1
RIGHT JOIN t ON dates.date = t.Expense_Date
FROM (
    SELECT Expense_Date, IFNULL(Sum(Total_Cost),0) as cost1
    FROM  Expenses
    RIGHT JOIN membership_userrecords ON Expenses.id = membership_userrecords.pkValue
    where membership_userrecords.memberID = 'kieran' AND membership_userrecords.tableName='Expenses'
    GROUP BY Expense_Date

) AS t
GROUP BY date ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT date, Expense_Date, cost1
FROM (
    SELECT Expense_Date, IFNULL(Sum(Total_Cost),0) as cost1
    FROM  Expenses
    RIGHT JOIN membership_userrecords ON Expenses.id = membership_userrecords.pkValue
    where membership_userrecords.memberID = 'kieran' AND membership_userrecords.tableName='Expenses'
    GROUP BY Expense_Date

) AS t
LEFT JOIN t ON dates.date = t.Expense_Date
GROUP BY date ;
```

Comment: like @rahul said you were missing the FROM clause

Comment: Thank you!!! You've helped me a lot here. My goal with this query is to show ALL dates from the dates table & only the expenses from the Expenses table that the user is permitted to see. Wherever there are no expenses, I was hoping to still output date & just show 0. However, this doesn't happen - I just get the limited record set according to user permissions. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Kieran when working with nested queries, first validate that your inner query gives you the correct data. The join should also be like this:

`SELECT date, Expense_Date, cost1
FROM (
    SELECT Expense_Date, IFNULL(Sum(Total_Cost),0) as cost1
    FROM  Expenses
    RIGHT JOIN membership_userrecords ON Expenses.id = membership_userrecords.pkValue
    where membership_userrecords.memberID = 'kieran' AND membership_userrecords.tableName='Expenses'
    GROUP BY Expense_Date

) AS t
RIGHT JOIN dates ON dates.date = t.Expense_Date
GROUP BY date ;`

Comment: Thank you - you've helped a lot. Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

Forget about second `SELECT` ... You are missing a `FROM` clause in your first `SELECT` itself as seen below

```
SELECT date, Expense_Date, cost1 <-- here
RIGHT JOIN t ON dates.date = t.Expense_Date
```